# Importing date from HTML into Django views

Tags: python, html, django

I'm fairly new to Django and I am facing a bit of a problem. I have my html template in which I have two html date fields - start_date and end_date. I want to pass the contents of those field into my views.py and then display data for that time period, but I am having trouble making it work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Relevant code:

**home.html**

```
  Select time period:
  <br>
  From:
  <input id = "start_date" type="date" name="From" value="{{data.start_date|date:"d/m/Y"}}">
  To:
  <input id = "end_date" type="date" name="To" value="{{data.end_date|date:"d/m/Y"}}">
  <input type = "submit">

{% for data in data.all %}
      {% if data.profile.user.username == user.username %} 

      <tr>
        <td>{{data.profile.user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{data.date}}</td>
      </tr>

      {% endif %}
      {% endfor  %}
```

**views.py**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

@login_required 
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user.username


    start_date = request.GET.get['start_date']
    end_date = request.GET.get['end_date']

    data = Data.objects.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date])

    context = {   

            'data': data,
            'cpu_hours_all': cpu_hours_all,
    }
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username


class Data(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True) 
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to explain what "I am having trouble making it work" actually means, so this will be at most a partial and kind of a "wild guess" answer, but anyway:

First you need to put your fields and submit in a  tag, with the proper HTTP method, and your fields "name" attribute (*not* the "id" attribute) must match what you're looking up in your view:

```
<form method="GET">
  <legend>Select time period:</legend>
  <br>
  From:
  <input id="start_date" type="date" name="start_date" value="{{start_date|date:"d/m/Y"}}">
  To:
  <input id="end_date" type="date" name="end_date" value="{{end_date|date:"d/m/Y"}}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also note that we're filling the fields with `{{ start_date }}` and `{{ end_date }}` - in your template's context, `data` is a `Queryset` and has no `start_date` nor `end_date` attributes.

Then in your view you have to use `request.GET.get()` properly:

```
@login_required 
def home(request):
    # ...
    start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
    end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
```

`.get()` is a method, it must be called, not subscripted (parens, not brackets). Note that until the user actually submits the form, those fields won't be in the querystring and `GET.get(...)` will return `None`, so you have to handle this case, either by providing default values to `.get()` or by testing if the form was submitted and not returning a queryset at all (or returning an empty queryset, or returning the whole unfiltered queryset etc, choice is yours).  Here's a version returning an empty queryset.

Also, since you're not using a Django `forms.Form`, what you will get here are raw unsanitized strings, while `Queryset.filter()` expects Python `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` objects, so you'll have to validate and convert those values manually:

```
# ...
parsed_start_date = None
parsed_end_date = None
if start_date and end_date:    
    errors = {}
    try:
        parsed_start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        errors["start_date"] = "Invalid date" # etc..
    try:
        parsed_end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        errors["end_date"] = "Invalid date" # etc..

if parsed_start_date and parsed_end_date:
    data = Data.objects.filter(date__range=[parsed_start_date, parsed_end_date])
else:
    data = Data.objects.none()  # empty queryset

context = {   
        'data': data,
        'errors': errors,
        'start_date': start_date,
        'end_date': end_date
       }

# etc
```

And then you have to change your template to accomodate those changes (don't try to apply the `|date` filter to strings, display errors...):

```
<form method="GET">
  Select time period:
  <br>
  From:
  <input id="start_date" type="date" name="start_date" value="{{start_date}}">
  {% if errors.start_date %}
      <span class="error">{{ errors.start_date }}</span>
  {% endif %}
  To:
  <input id="end_date" type="date" name="end_date" value="{{end_date}}">
  {% if errors.end_date %}
      <span class="error">{{ errors.end_date }}</span>
  {% endif %}

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that [using a Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) would make it much less painfull (and much more robust too).

Also, it seems you are not really proficient with HTML nor Python. Django is a very handy python web framework but it still requires you to have at least a basic knowledge of HTTP, HTML and, of course, Python. I kindly suggest you take some time learning those topics if you hope to get anything done.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and comprehensive response. I will read up on the suggested topics.